# How to add decorator to args param in graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

can't add decorator `@IsUUID()` from `class-validator` to my param `productI`, I don't want use additional dto. How to fix it?

```
@UseGuards(new AuthGuard(['user', 'admin']))
@Mutation(() => ProductEntity)
async updateProduct(
  @User() user,
  @Args('productId', {})
  //@IsUUID() Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
  productId: string,
  @Args('inputs', {})
  inputs: UpdateProductInputDto,
): Promise<ProductEntity> {
  return this.productService.updateProduct(user.id, productId, inputs);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way around it. If you want to use `@IsUUID()` and the `ValidationPipe`, you **have** to use a class DTO. If you're just looking to validate the `UUID` though, you could use the [`ParseUUIDPipe`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/parse-uuid.pipe.ts). `@Args('productId', {}, new ParseUUIDPipe({ version: 4 }))`